# What is wrong with my bash script: var=(command1 | command2)?

Tags: bash, syntax-error

I have a line in my bash script:

```
  foldername=(echo ${newpath[start]} | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: ";} {print $1;}')
```

it was working properly. But after doing some edits on other parts of my script file, it gives me the following error:

```
line 98: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
line 98: `      foldername=( echo ${newpath[start]} | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: ";} {print $1;}' )'
```

Any one could tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `$` after `=`:

```
foldername=$(echo ${newpath[start]} | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/: ";} {print $1;}')
```

Comment: That solved my problem, but strange thing is that it was working properly without `$`!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your command line:

```
a=(echo yes| sed 's@yes@no@g')
```

You'll get

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

That's because you are missing '$' in front of the opening parenthesis. The following works

```
a=$(echo yes| sed 's@yes@no@g')
```